# QBO3 deployments targeting a custom folder

Tags: powershell, msbuild, webdeploy

I'm trying to implement a MSBuild/deployment script for a customized QBO3 installation. I can build and publish to a remote Dev machine with the script that I currently have. However, my msbuild script is copying my bin folder to `C:/inetpub/wwwroot` and I need them in a different directory (`C:/inetpub/devqcc.quandis.net`).

Within my script, is there a way for me to specify a different destination folder for the files to get copied into?

Answer (score 0):

The qbo3 MSBuild targets are designed to support both a file system deployment, and deployment via WebDeploy.

**File System Deployments**

To target a custom folder for file system deployments, specify a PublishFolder parameter:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild' .\qbo3.Sample.proj /p:"PublishFolder=c:\inetpub\devqcc.quandis.net"
```

**WebDeploy**

To target a custom folder with WebDeploy (which sounds like your use case), specify a SiteName parameter:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild' .\qbo3.Sample.proj /p:"SiteName=devqcc.quandis.net,Server=1.2.3.4,User=myUserName,Pwd=secret"
```

WebDeploy does not write to a file path; instead, it communicates with IIS and IIS determines where to place the files. This implies that your target box must already **have a website configured** to use the folder you are targeting.

For example, assume you have the following file structure on disk:

- c:\inetpub\wwwroot
- c:\inetpub\devqcc.quandis.net
- c:\inetpub\uatqcc

with cooresponding IIS websites:

- Default Web Site: root folder is c:\inetpub\wwwroot
- devqcc.quandis.net: root folder is c:\inetpub\devqcc.quandis.net
- uatqcc: root folder is c:\inetpub\uatqcc.quandis.net

To deploy to the `c:\inetpub\devqcc.quandis.net` folder, tell WebDeploy to use the `devqcc.quandis.net` website:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild' .\qbo3.Sample.proj /p:"SiteName=devqcc.quandis.net,Server=1.2.3.4,User=myUserName,Pwd=secret"
```

To deploy to the `c:\inetpub\uatqcc.quandis.net` folder, tell WebDeploy to use the `uatqcc` website (*note this example the site name != the folder name*):

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild' .\qbo3.Sample.proj /p:"SiteName=uatqcc,Server=1.2.3.4,User=myUserName,Pwd=secret"
```

If you review the `qbo3.Sample.proj` file, note that it provides defaults for both the `PublishFolder` (for file system deployments) and `SiteName` (for remote deployments via WebDeploy):

```
<PublishFolder Condition=" '$(PublishFolder)'==''">c:\inetpub\wwwroot</PublishFolder>
<SiteName Condition=" '$(SiteName)'==''">Default Web Site</SiteName>
```